# Duplicate array object when change dynamic value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I make small marketing app where user select screen for put commercial on it. 
Flow is next, user select date range and get from API all free screens with available impressions. User select screen and add them to cart. Every screen have data with available impressions.

Here is cart table

```
 |ID   | Available impressions (input) |
 |1000 |       5000                    |
 |1004 |       7855                    |
 |1098 |       9688                    |
 |1111 |       1022                    |
 total: 23565 (input field)
```

This is working like I expect and this is ok, I post this to API and everything is ok.

CODE:

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Available impressions</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tboda>
       <tr ng-repeat="item in myCartItems | unique: 'id'">
          <td>item.id</td>
          <td><input type="number" ng-model="item.available_imp" ng-blur="sendCustomSelectedImpressions(item.id, item.available_imp)" ng-max="item.available_imp"</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

And I push this data to array

```
$scope.sendCustomSelectedImpressions = function(id, numberOfImpressions){
      $scope.myCartItems.push({
        'id': id,
        'campaignImpressions': numberOfImpressions
      });
}
```

**Problem 1**

Problem is if we input new value in a row with impressions, and before we send to API, again input new value, in my json I don't get only new value, I get all value inputted before, like in JSON bellow

```
{"campaign_items": [
{"id": 1000, "impressions": 5000},//duplicate, this is initial, i don't need this, i need new
{"id": 1004, "impressions": 7855},
{"id": 1098, "impressions": 9688},
{"id": 1111, "impressions": 1022},
{"id": 1000, "impressions": 6000}, //duplicate, when i try to input another number
{"id": 1000, "impressions": 4561}, //i only need this last i entered
]}
```

How to get only input I entered before submit, without all this before, without duplicate???

**PROBLEM 2**

For this problem, I still don't have any code, because I need to do this, but I need some help with logic.

If you look at table example, you will see, I have `TOTAL`, also input field. 
When ng-table is loaded I sum all impressions in a row and show total. That's ok.
Every screen has a different max total number, and if I enter another number in the total field, for example, instead of `23565` I enter lower number `19000` I need evenly add to all selected screen. The problem here is, a screen with `ID 1111` have only `1022` impressions, but a screen with `ID 9688` have `9688` impressions. 
For me, the solution is, calculate for how much in percentage initial `sum` number is changed, and when I get a result, decrease by the same percentage every screen impressions. If someone has any another solution, or have some idea for code pls share with us.

Thnx again

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem, you can remove the objects with that ID before you push new data. Assuming you can use the `filter` function (otherwise you need to loop). This way you will remove the id to be pushed in the next `push` statement.

```
$scope.sendCustomSelectedImpressions = function(id, numberOfImpressions){
      $scope.myCartItems = $scope.myCartItems.filter(item => item.id !== id);

      $scope.myCartItems.push({
        'id': id,
        'campaignImpressions': numberOfImpressions
      });
}
```

Comment: thank you... I try this with splice but the filter is the solution. Thank you.... sry I will accept your answer later if someone gives me answer for the second problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think for **PROBLEM 1** you may not need to push new values, instead you can just update $scope.myCartItems.

```
$scope.sendCustomSelectedImpressions (id, numberOfImpressions) {
    if (!numberOfImpressions) return; // Check, if input is not empty (not undegined or null)
    $scope.myCartItems[id - 1].impressions = numberOfImpressions; // change existing object items
};
```

I've made a simple stackbltz app with example (Angularjs + ES6). I hope it helps :)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-tn1zs9?embed=1&file=home/home.controller.js

Comment: Be aware that this solution relies on implicit rules that don't really correspond to the OP use case: the `id` here must start by `1`, with `0` you'd have `$scope.myCartItems[-1]` which would mess with the array length. It also relies on the ids to be consecutive, as `var a = []; a[1000] = 'test';` creates 1000 empty elements before 'test'. If the OP wants to keep the display and current `myCartItems`, this solution doesn't fit

Comment: @Kaddath thnx for info. If I use track by $index and then `$scope.myCartItems[index]` is this better solution?